# How to use libusb with libevent?

Tags: c++, c, libusb, libevent, libusb-1.0

I'm writing an event-driven application using libevent, and I need to do a USB transfer using libusb-1.0.

I wanted to use [libusb_get_pollfds](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__poll.html#gab1a72869a926552b27a6c667695df3a2) to get a list of files descriptors (in `fds`) and add them to libevent like this:

```
const struct libusb_pollfd **fds = libusb_get_pollfds(device->context);

const struct libusb_pollfd *it = *fds;
for(;it != NULL; ++it) {
    cout << "Adding fd: " << it->fd << ", " << it->events << endl;
    struct event * ev = event_new(base_, 
        it->fd, it->events | EV_PERSIST, 
        callbacks::libusb_cb, this);
    event_add(ev, 0);
    libusb_fds_events.insert(std::make_pair(it->fd, ev));
}

free(fds);

// (...)

// And the callback function:
void callbacks::libusb_cb(evutil_socket_t fd, short what, void *arg) {
    Server *s = reinterpret_cast<Server*>(arg);
    libusb_handle_events_timeout(s->device_->context, 0);
}
```

Also, I use [libusb_set_pollfd_notifiers](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__poll.html#ga1b7b2deb193f2e9ffda5e727361d7e67) to add/remove fds from `libusb_fds_events`.

The problem is I get many strange fds on the list returned by libusb (for example, I get `stdin`(!) many times with event equals to 0).

Am I using it in right way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an error in code. It should have been:

```
const struct libusb_pollfd **it = fds;
for(;*it != NULL; ++it) {
    cout << "Adding fd: " << (*it)->fd << ", " << (*it)->events << endl;
    struct event * ev = event_new(base_, 
        (*it)->fd, (*it)->events | EV_PERSIST, 
        callbacks::libusb_cb, this);
    event_add(ev, 0);
    libusb_fds_events.insert(std::make_pair((*it)->fd, ev));
}
```